# "La tant attendu..." ou "la tant attendue..." ?

Tags: adjectifs, accord, participe-passé

La quelle des deux phrases suivantes est juste ?

1. *La tant attendu mise à jour  ...*
2. *La tant attendue mise à jour  ...*

*La tant attendu* n'a pas de côte sur google mais d'après la règle II.A sur [cette page](https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-13760.php) c'est le bon choix car *attendu* est placé devant le nom qu'il qualifie.

En revanche, *La tant attendue* est beaucoup plus fréquent sur google donc laisse penser que l'accord est attendu (sans jeu de mot).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On connait déjà le genre du nom qualifié au moment d'écrire le participe passé donc accord :

> **La** tant attend**ue** mise à jour...
>
> **Le** tant attend**u** logiciel...

De toute façon, on n'est pas dans un cas d'utilisation d'auxiliaire être ou avoir, donc l'accord s'impose toujours.

Comment: Merci. Par rapport à votre dernière phrase, quelle est donc la différence avec la règle II. A qui concerne le participe passé sans auxiliaire ? Ici, *attendu* n'est-il pas un participe passé ?

Comment: La règle à la quelle vous faite référence n'est pas complète: à mon sens, il faut comprendre que *attendu* est invariable s'il est avant un groupe nominal (pas juste le nom), et utilisé alors comme préposition au sens de "en raison de " (c'est peu courant, sauf en langage juridique). Ex: *attendu les circonstances, l'accusé est acquitté*.